# Django : How to get month data in week wise format in django

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField()
    model = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

This is my Model ( Car )
If I pass date params ( 2021-07-09 ), I need last 1 month of data from this date. ( Eg : 2021-07-9 - 30 DAYS ). I'm using Django Rest framework.
I need 30 days of data's in week format ( 7 days data in one set like wise..)

can anyone help me to come out of this situation..

Thank you...!!

Comment: Can you share what you have already tried? What exact issue are you encountering?

Comment: I'm getting data within particular date ranges using filter method.

But I exactly need in week wise format, One month we can consider for 4 weeks, Then 1 week data, 2 week data upto 4th week data

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Could you also be more specific about what exactly you're trying to achieve (maybe some example output/response/...)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, the logic is simply:

1. get QuerySet of entries for each week.
2. append QuerySet into list.

```
    import datetime
    monthly = list()
    for i in range(0,4):
        end_date = datetime.strptime(passed_date, '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.timedelta(7 * i)
        start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(7 * (i + 1))
        _qs = Car.objects.filter(date__gte='start_date', date__lt='end_date')
        monthly.append(_qs)
```

Comment: This works fine, But I need the data in weeks format. Example
start_date + 7 days data ( one set , like wise )

Thanks for your valuable reply

Comment: edited the answer to reflect actual code